# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2901).

Comment: Hi Grace. In your example above, for the image title you have "_Tagline to show on mouseover_". I have not seen that any of the ads on this page show this title on mouseover. It would be possible to get something to appear when doing a mouseover by specifying tooltip text, which goes after the image URL (e.g. `[1]: http://image-url (ToolTip text)` ). Is this something that we can do without invalidating our submission? You are very clear that we are to use the provided format and not deviate from it, so I have been assuming that adding this is a deviation. Am I right or can we add a Tool Tip?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Within this thread, the text there is only shown as title text, which isn't mouseover text. However, to my knowledge, when the ad is served on the main site's sidebar proper, it should show up as proper mouseover text. I can't actually confirm this now myself because no ads seem to want to load at all for me, but I'll have someone look into it if they're not showing up for some reason.

Comment: It's been confirmed that the mouseover does work properly on the actual ads served - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsMUS.png

Comment: Grace: awesome! Thank you very much for confirming that        ...

Comment: @GraceNote thank you. I've just confirmed it, too, and I as coming to inform all but you had beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 30):

[image: Instance migrations and best practice implementations have never been safer, faster or freer.]

Answer (score 24):

[image: Designed to complement DBA.SE, by enabling contributors to share editable database scripts and examples]

Answer (score 22):

[image: Plan Explorer - Unrivaled execution plan analysis. Now completely free!]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: I downvoted. Largely because the twitter functionality of Stack Exchange is horrible from any aspect. If you really want to keep up with SE, use the RSS functionality. Which is actually pretty decent and much better at this. That said, it's a good example. I just don't want to push that service.

Answer (score 13):

[image: The world's most advanced open source database.]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Head over to Aireforge to learn more]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Over 180 free SQLCLR functions and stored procedures that improve and extend what you can do in T-SQL]

Comment: I thought it was a tick-tack-toe game implemented in SQL!

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It probably doesn't help that the tooltip containing the tagline doesn't seem to be working (at least not for me on any of the ones posted on this page). So, maybe not tic-tac-toe, but 3 in a row = you win (which is the overall goal of SQL# :-)

Comment: I've added a tooltip. Edit as you want!

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks. I considered doing that but refrained due to the statements in the question regarding "_All answers should be in the exact form of_" and "_Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**_". How about I remove it for now and post a comment on the question asking if we can do that. The other reason I was hesitant to try it was that the question seems to imply that the "title" of the image mark-down is what will be used for the "mouseover", which I took to mean the tooltip, but there could be another usage within their ad rotation system. I will ask / confirm.

Comment: I saw how to do it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318932/adding-image-reference-in-markdown-creates-excessive-text/319299#319299 I suppose the method to add images with kinks/tooltips was changed at some point but the community promotion usage text was not updated. But sure, go ahead and ask the mods!

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I don't think you are wrong, I just prefer to know that you are correct :-). I've been caught before doing things that made perfect sense only to be reprimanded that, as rational as it appeared to be, it was still a violation of stated rules. So, I will let the rule-maker(s) render an official ruling on it: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/community-promotion-ads-2018#comment5318_2901